# facing a problem with python identity operators

Tags: python, pycharm, operators, identity

recently i learned about python identity operators and i facing a problem while i using it in python shell and pycharm .

my shell code be like ->

```
>>> a = 6000
>>> b = 6000
>>> b is a
False
```

it ans me False .

but when i using pycharm like ->

```
a = 6000
b = 6000
print( b is a )
```

it ans me True .

Can anyone explain me where i am going wrong and what is actual difference between python shell and ide ?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/494134

Comment: I get True evaluation both running it in iPython and as script from command prompt.

Comment: thanks a lot @JohnGordon , I've got the Perfect Explanation here .

Comment: Or this one for a more general explanation https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/1609514